# Returning Doubles in haskell

Tags: haskell

Now what I want to do is to write another function, triangle_areas (note the use of plural here), that takes a list of Doubles, treats each consecutive group of three Doubles as the lengths of the three sides of a triangle, uses triangle_area to calculate its area; and after processing all Doubles in the list, returns all calculated areas as a list of Doubles.

Here is my code so far.

```
triangle_area :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
triangle_area a b c = sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c))
    where s = (a + b + c) / 2.0

triangle_areas :: [Double] -> [Double]
triangle_areas xs = []
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Now did you have a question?

Comment: use patterns - depending on what you want `triangle_areas (x:y:z:ds)` or `triangle_areas (x:ds@(y:z:_))`

Comment: probably need to check the triangle inequality is satisfied for the sides as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use pattern matching to get the first three elements of the input, then recurse. It's simplest if you assume `triangle_areas` is always called with a list whose length is a multiple of 3.

```
triangle_areas :: [Double] -> [Double]
triangle_areas [] = []
triangle_areas (a:b:c:xs) = triangle_area a b c : triangle_areas xs
```

For lists with an extra element or two, there are many options. One is to simply ignore them.

```
-- Case 3
triangle_areas _ = []
```

Another is to simple return an error

```
-- Case 3
triangle_areas _ = error "Incomplete final set"
```

Yet another is to return an `Either` value

```
triangle_areas :: [Double] -> Either String [Double]
triangle_areas [] = Right []
triangle_areas (a:b:c:xs) = Right $ triangle_area a b c : triangle_areas xs
triangle_areas _ = Left "Incomplete final set"
```

And there are others.

Comment: `triangle_area` cannot be concatenated like that (it's not a list). Also this fails to pattern match for lists of length 1 and 2.

Comment: I specifically said I was assuming an input list whose length is a multiple of 3. There are many ways to handle other lists: ignore them, as in your answer, raise an exception, return an `Either a [Double]` value for some appropriate type `a`, etc.

Comment: The user can pick a way to handle the exception; I think it's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: It's no weaker than your solution, which is to silently ignore extra input. I was just up front about my assumption.